# Specifying Ubuntu version for a dokku container

Tags: ubuntu, dokku

I've installed dokku on Ubuntu 16.04, and deployed an app on it.
Looks like the app's container is based on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
# dokku run myapp bash
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

I want the app's environment to be 16.04 also. How do I control this? Does it depend on which buildpack is used? Which buildpack should I use for a  small Python 3.5 / Flask web application?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on buildpacks, I wrote a Dockerfile. This way I can specify the exact base OS image I want.

[dokku docs on Dockerfile deployment](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/methods/dockerfiles/)